# divide two SUM of Two interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that return 24 rows. I want to divide `SUM` of tirst 12 `index` into `SUM` next 12 `index`. I use `ROW_NUMBER` like this but I can't filter `row`. How I can do this?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Month] DESC) AS Row,[Year], [Month],
   PCode_9, [Index] 
FROM tbl08
WHERE PCode = @Code AND
  (([Year] * 12 + [Month]) <= @CurrentYearMonth) AND
  (([Year] * 12 + [Month]) >= @FCurrentYearMonth) AND row > 12   <-- ERROR
ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Month] DESC
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Your Query Returns 24 rowsTry Like This

```
 Select t.*,(Sum(Case when row<=12 then Index else 0 End)/
Sum(Case when row>12 then Index else 0 End)) as Result from
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Month] DESC) AS Row,[Year], [Month],
PCode_9, [Index] 
FROM tbl08
WHERE PCode = @Code AND
(([Year] * 12 + [Month]) <= @CurrentYearMonth) AND
(([Year] * 12 + [Month]) >= @FCurrentYearMonth) AND row > 12   <-- ERROR
ORDER BY [Year] DESC,[Month] DESC
) t
```